# How to reference ${catalina.base} in logback.groovy config?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, logback

I am trying to deploy a webapp that uses logback's groovy config files.

I saw that in xml files you can reference ${catalina.base}

Is there a way to reference that from logback.groovy? I want a reference to tomcat home or logs folder. I want it to work even if I don't have the environment variable set.

If I write it as is I get "No such property: catalina"

I am trying to make my logs go to tomcat/logs/... regardless of the hostname. I want to make it webapp specific, not in tomcat/conf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`catalina.base` is a system property which is set by Tomcat startup scripts (catalina.sh, catalina.bat).
When working with  logback's groovy config files you can simply read the value of this system property into a variable and use it, for example:

```
def catalinaBase = System.properties['catalina.base']

appender("FILE", FileAppender) {
    file = "${catalinaBase}/mylog.log"
    ...
}
```